# HTML form dropdown menu specify number range

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to specify number range in drop-down menu list like 1-24 from example i am currently doing following

```
<select name="hour">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
...
...
<option value="24">24</option>
</select>
```

is there any way we can say use 1-24 and it dynamically create drop-down menu, I guess we need to use Javascript but i don't know how to code them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need Javascript, you can use a PHP for loop:

```
<select name="hour">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @Satish haha! Don't forget to mark as best answer if it was useful :)

Comment: why not...i will but you have to wait for 10 min :)

Answer (score 6):

This answer might be useful now. With HTML5 it made simpler. we don't need javascript to do the same. Supported in most of the modern browsers. Could not check for older IE versions.

```
<label for="hour">Hour:</label>
<input type="number" id="hour" min="1" max="24" />
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer now.

Answer (score 4):

If you only wish to use Javascript, you could do something like:

```
for(var i=1; i<=24; i++){
    var select = document.getElementById("hours");
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
    select.options.add(option);
    option.text = i;
    option.value = i;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x4Jh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Even i have also figured out following after your example:

```
<?php
echo "<select>";
for ($h = 1; $h <= 24; $h++) echo "<option value='$h'>$h</option>";
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP [Range — Create an array containing a range of elements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
echo '<select name="hour">';
foreach (range(1,24) as $number) {
        echo '<option value='.$number.'>'.$number.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```