# datepicker/javascript elements not working on every page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im hoping this issue is really obvious to someone with more experience.
I have put together some form features that seem to be working fine on the first booking page but not on the second, i have had to adapt some from a template and cobble together so i thought there is something in one of the scripts that is conflicting but cant seem to find out what is causing it to not load on the second page, i do still need to add in the form actions and php file but want to get this figured out before i continue.

working as desired on this page

http://www.dystopiart.co.uk/Beffay_frame/chalet_booking.html
but not on 
http://www.dystopiart.co.uk/Beffay_frame/apartment_booking.html

I have now made some changes as advised - datepicker identical but still behaving the same, as i wasnt sure where the problem is i wasn't sure which ones to post, from comments looks like these ones are most appropriate, there appears to be an error in the selection/option dropdown js, any ideas on how i rectify?

html page1

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN head -->
<head>
<!--Meta Tags-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
<!-- Title -->
<title>Beffay- Book Chalet</title>  <!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css3menu1/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="fonts/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="manifest" href="images/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#e9edf2">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/favicons/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="images/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#e9edf2">
<!-- JavaScript For IE -->  
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- END head -->   
</head>
<body ontouchstart="" >
<section id="titles">  
<div id="logo">   
<h1>Chalet Beffay<h1>  </div>
<input type="checkbox" id="css3menu-switcher" class="c3m-switch-input">     
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">         
<li class="switch"><label onclick="" for="css3menu-switcher"></label></li>
<li class="topfirst"><a href="index.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Home</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="index.html#about">About Us</a></li>    
<li><a href="index.html#news">News</a></li>  </ul></li>         
<li class="topmenu"><a href="chalet.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Chalet</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="chalet.html#gallery">Gallery</a></li>      
<li><a href="chalet.html#ameneties">Ameneties</a></li>      
<li><a href="chalet.html#rates">Rates</a></li>      
<li><a href="chalet.html#layout">Layout</a></li>    
<li><a href="chalet.html#brocPDF">Brochure PDF</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="topmenu"><a href="apartment.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Apartment</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="apartment.html#gallery">Gallery</a></li>  
<li><a href="apartment.html#ameneties">Ameneties</a></li>   
<li><a href="apartment.html#rates">Rates</a></li>   
<li><a href="apartment.html#layout">Layout</a></li>     
<li><a href="apartment.html#broaPDF">Brochure PDF</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="topmenu"><a href="location.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Location</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="location.html#directions">Directions</a></li>      
<li><a href="location.html#activities">Activities</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="topmenu"><a href="reviews.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Reviews</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="reviews.html#customers">Customers</a></li>     
<li><a href="reviews.html#reviews">Review Us</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="topmenu"><a class="pressed" href="#" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Availability</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="chalet_booking.html">Chalet</a></li>   
<li><a href="apartment_booking.html">Apartment</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="toplast"><a href="contact.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;">Contact Us</a></li>  
</ul>   
<!-- End css3menu.com BODY section -->
</section>  
    <hr class="space10" />
<section id="wrapper">  
<div class="clearfix" id="statichead">  
    <img src="images/calender.jpg" alt="" />          
</div>    <!-- BEGIN .content-wrapper -->
<div id="chalet">         
<div class="content-wrapper clearfix">  
    <h3 class="title-style11">Booking</h3>  <!-- BEGIN .one-third -->       
<div class="two-third clearfix">    
    <h3 class="title-style2">The Chalet</h3>    
    <p>A traditional wooden chalet built approximately 25 years ago and completely modernized by the present owners who have lived there for nearly ten years.<br>
    It provides a very comfortable and relaxing environment with stunning views.
    </p>    </div>      
<div class="one-third clearfix last-col">  
    <img src="images/chaletms.jpg" alt="" class="image-style1 respond-img" />   
</div>      
    <hr class="space7" />   <!-- BEGIN .booking-step-wrapper -->    
<div class="content-wrapper clearfix">      
<div id="bookingcal">                               
    <iframe src="./calendar/index.php" allowfullscreen></iframe>                        
</div></div>      
    <hr class="space7" />
<div class="content-wrapper clearfix ">
<div id="priceList1"><h3 class="title-style2">Rates</h3>
<div class="inset clearfix">    
    <h3><strong>Rates per week, Saturday to Saturday</strong></h3>      </div>
<div id="priceList">
<table cellspacing="0"  id="pricesTable" summary="Price List">
    <colgroup>  <col id="Times" />
    <col id="From" />
    <col id="To" />
    <col id="WeeklyPrice" />  </colgroup>
 <thead>
    <tr>    <th class="DateHeader">Dates</th>      <th class="PriceFromHeader">From</th>    <th class="PriceToHeader">To</th>   <th class="WeeklyPriceHeader">Weekly Price (Sat-Sat)</th>   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr class="">   
     <td class="DateColumn">Christmas & New Year</td>   
     <td class="PriceFromColumn">19th Dec</td>      
     <td  class="PriceToColumn">3rd January</td>    
     <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;1,950.00</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">    
     <td class="DateColumn">January</td>    
     <td class="PriceFromColumn">3rd January</td>   
     <td  class="PriceToColumn">30th January</td>   
     <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;1,250.00</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr class="">   
     <td class="DateColumn">February</td>   
     <td class="PriceFromColumn">30th January</td>      
     <td  class="PriceToColumn">27th February</td>      
     <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;1,850.00</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">    
     <td class="DateColumn">March</td>      
     <td class="PriceFromColumn">27th Feb</td>      
     <td  class="PriceToColumn">2nd April</td>      
     <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;1,580.00</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr class="">   
     <td class="DateColumn">April</td>      
     <td class="PriceFromColumn">2nd April</td>     
     <td  class="PriceToColumn">1st May</td>    
     <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;1,150.00</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">    
     <td class="DateColumn">Summer 2016</td>    
     <td class="PriceFromColumn">2nd May</td>   
     <td  class="PriceToColumn">TBC</td>    
     <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;750.00</td>   
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<div class="inset clearfix">    
    <h3><strong>Long weekend and alternate change over days may be available subject to bookings.</strong></h3>     </div>
</div></div>        
    <h2 class=" inset booklink"><strong><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i> 20% off <a href="apartment.html">Apartment</a> rate if booked with the Chalet</strong></h2>
    <hr class="space9" />
    </div>      
<div id="confirmation"> 
<!-- reservation1 -->
<form class="booking-form" name="bookchalet" action="booking1.html" method="post">          
<div class="booking-side-wrapper clearfix">                 
<div class="booking-side">                  <!-- BEGIN .widget -->          
<div class="widget">  
<div class="widget-reservation-box">    
<h4 class="title-style2">Reservation</h4>    
<ul><li><span>Accomodation: </span> The Chalet</li>  
    <li><span>With Apartment? </span><div id="switchbox>
<div class="switch">
<input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
<label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
<input id="cmn-toggle-4" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
<label for="cmn-toggle-4"></label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
<input id="cmn-toggle-7" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" type="checkbox">
<label for="cmn-toggle-7" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></label>
</div></li>     
    <li><span>Requested Dates: </span>       
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="one-half-form">
    <label for="open_date_from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="datefrom" name="book_date_from" value="Check In" class="datepicker">
</div>
<div class="one-half-form last-col">
    <label for="open_date_to">To</label>
    <input type="text" id="dateto" name="book_date_to" value="Check Out"   class="datepicker">
</div></div></li>   
<li><span>Number Of Guests: </span><select id="guests"></select></li>   
<li><span>Total Days: <select id="days"></select></li>      
<li><span>Todays Date: </span>  <p id="today"></p></li> </ul>
<!-- END .widget-reservation-box -->  </div>            <!-- END .widget -->        </div>        <!-- END .content-wrapper -->  </div>
    </div>
<!-- booking form -->               
<div class="booking-main-wrapper">                  
<div class="booking-main">    
    <h4 class="title-style2">Your Details</h4>
<div class="input-left">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">    
<label for="email_address">Email Address</label>
 <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address">
<label for="phone_number">Telephone Number</label>
 <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number">
<label for="address_line1">Address Line 1</label>
 <input type="text" name="address_line1" id="address_line1">
    </div>
<div class="input-right">
<label for="address_line2">Address Line 2</label>
 <input type="text" name="address_line2" id="address_line2">
<label for="city">City</label>
 <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
<label for="state_county">State / County</label>
 <input type="text" name="state_county" id="state_county">
<label for="zip_postcode">Zip / Postcode</label>
 <input type="text" name="zip_postcode" id="zip_postcode">
<label for="country">Country</label>
 <input type="text" name="country" id="country">
    </div>
<label for="special_requirements">Special Requirments</label>   
 <textarea name="special_requirements" id="special_requirements" rows="10"></textarea>
<p class="terms"><input type="checkbox" name="terms"> I confirm I have read and agree to the <a href="#" style="color:#CC0000;font-weight:800;">terms and conditions</a> and wish to place a booking</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input class="button1" type="submit" value="Request Booking Now" />    </form>          <hr class="space4"/>        </div>              </div>
</section>      
<!-- BEGIN #footer -->  <div id="footer">       <!-- BEGIN .content-wrapper -->     <div class="content-wrapper clearfix">                                      <!-- BEGIN #footer-bottom -->       <div id="footer-bottom" class="clearfix">
<nav class="secondary-navigation">      
<ul class="fr">
<li><a href="chalet.html">Chalet</a><span>/</span></li>
<li><a href="apartment.html">Apartment</a><span>/</span></li>
<li><a href="chalet_booking.html">Book Now</a><span>/</span></li>
<li><a href="location.html#directions">Directions &amp; Map</a><span>/</span></li>      
</ul>  </nav>    <!-- END .clearfix -->
</div> </div>       
<footer id="copyright">             
<div class="dyst">      
<p class="fl">&copy; Web adaptation, styling and graphics by</p><a href="http://www.dystopiart.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/DystopiART_Small.png" alt="DystopiART"></a>  
</div>  
<div class="social"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Beffay" class="link facebook" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook-square"></span></a>     
</div>  
<div class="rounded-corners scroll">    
<span class="to-top"><a href="#logo"><i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-2x">
</i></a></span>  </div>             
</footer>
</div></div></div></div></div>
<!-- Smooth Scroll -->
<script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>    
<!-- END body -->
</body>
</html>
```

page 2

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN head -->
<head>
<!--Meta Tags-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- Title -->
<title>Beffay- Book Apartment</title>
    <!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css3menu1/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="fonts/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css" />
<!-- End css3menu.com HEAD section -->
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="manifest" href="images/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#e9edf2">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/favicons/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="images/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#e9edf2">
<!-- JavaScript For IE -->
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- END head -->   
</head>
<body ontouchstart="" >
<section id="titles">
    <div id="logo">   
<h1>Chalet Beffay<h1>  </div>
<input type="checkbox" id="css3menu-switcher" class="c3m-switch-input">     
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">         
<li class="switch"><label onclick="" for="css3menu-switcher"></label></li>
<li class="topfirst"><a href="index.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Home</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="index.html#about">About Us</a></li>    
<li><a href="index.html#news">News</a></li>  </ul></li>         
<li class="topmenu"><a href="chalet.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Chalet</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="chalet.html#gallery">Gallery</a></li>      
<li><a href="chalet.html#ameneties">Ameneties</a></li>      
<li><a href="chalet.html#rates">Rates</a></li>      
<li><a href="chalet.html#layout">Layout</a></li>    
<li><a href="chalet.html#brocPDF">Brochure PDF</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="topmenu"><a href="apartment.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Apartment</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="apartment.html#gallery">Gallery</a></li>  
<li><a href="apartment.html#ameneties">Ameneties</a></li>   
<li><a href="apartment.html#rates">Rates</a></li>   
<li><a href="apartment.html#layout">Layout</a></li>     
<li><a href="apartment.html#broaPDF">Brochure PDF</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="topmenu"><a href="location.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Location</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="location.html#directions">Directions</a></li>      
<li><a href="location.html#activities">Activities</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="topmenu"><a href="reviews.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Reviews</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="reviews.html#customers">Customers</a></li>     
<li><a href="reviews.html#reviews">Review Us</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="topmenu"><a class="pressed" href="#" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;"><span>Availability</span></a>  
<ul>    <li><a href="chalet_booking.html">Chalet</a></li>   
<li><a href="apartment_booking.html">Apartment</a></li>  
</ul></li>          
<li class="toplast"><a href="contact.html" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;">Contact Us</a></li>  
</ul> 
</section>  
<hr class="space10" />
<section id="wrapper">
    <div class="clearfix" id="statichead">
    <img src="images/calender.jpg" alt="" />        
    </div>      
    <!-- BEGIN .content-wrapper -->
<div id="apartment">        
    <div class="content-wrapper clearfix">
    <h3 class="title-style11">Booking</h3>
    <!-- BEGIN .one-third -->
            <div class="two-third clearfix">
        <h3 class="title-style2">The Apartment</h3>
        <p>A completely separate apartment providing privacy and great views. Can be rented separately or provide additional accommodation for a family or friends staying in the chalet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third clearfix last-col">  <img src="images/beffayms.jpg" alt="" class="image-style1 respond-img" /></div>
        </div>
        <hr class="space7" />
        <!-- BEGIN .booking-step-wrapper -->
        <div class="content-wrapper clearfix">
        <div id="bookingcal">
        <iframe src="./calendar2/index.php" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="space7" />
<div class="content-wrapper clearfix ">
  <div id="priceList2"><h3 class="title-style2">Rates</h3>
<div class="inset clearfix">
        <h3><strong>Rates per week, Saturday to Saturday</strong></h3>
        </div>
<div id="priceList2">
<table cellspacing="0"  id="pricesTable2" summary="Price List">
<colgroup>
    <col id="Times" />
    <col id="From" />
    <col id="To" />
    <col id="WeeklyPrice" />    
 </colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="DateHeader">Dates</th>
        <th class="PriceFromHeader">From</th>
        <th class="PriceToHeader">To</th>
        <th class="WeeklyPriceHeader">Weekly Price (Sat-Sat)</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
        <td class="DateColumn">Early December</td>
        <td class="PriceFromColumn">5th Dec</td>
        <td  class="PriceToColumn">19th Dec</td>
        <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;250.00</td>
        </tr>
<tr class="">
        <td class="DateColumn">Christmas & New Year</td>
        <td class="PriceFromColumn">19th Dec</td>
        <td  class="PriceToColumn">3rd January</td>
        <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;850.00</td>
        </tr>
<tr class="odd">
        <td class="DateColumn">January</td>
        <td class="PriceFromColumn">3rd January</td>
        <td  class="PriceToColumn">30th January</td>
        <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;550.00</td>
        </tr>
<tr class="">
        <td class="DateColumn">February</td>
        <td class="PriceFromColumn">30th January</td>
        <td  class="PriceToColumn">27th February</td>
        <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;750.00</td>
        </tr>
<tr class="odd">
        <td class="DateColumn">March</td>
        <td class="PriceFromColumn">27th Feb</td>
        <td  class="PriceToColumn">2nd April</td>
        <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;480.00</td>
        </tr>
<tr class="">
        <td class="DateColumn">April</td>
        <td class="PriceFromColumn">2nd April</td>
        <td  class="PriceToColumn">1st May</td>
        <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;650.00</td>
        </tr>
<tr class="odd">
        <td class="DateColumn">Summer 2016</td>
        <td class="PriceFromColumn">2nd May</td>
        <td  class="PriceToColumn">TBC</td>
        <td class="WeeklyPriceColumn">&pound;250.00</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="inset clearfix">
        <h3><strong>Long weekend and alternate change over days may be available subject to bookings.</strong></h3>
        </div>
</div>
<h2 class="inset booklink"><strong><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i> 20% off Apartment rate if booked with the <a href="chalet.html">Chalet</a></strong></h2>
<hr class="space9" />
</div>      
<div id="confirmation2">    
<!-- reservation1 -->
<form class="booking-form" name="bookapartment" action="booking2.html" method="post">       
<div class="booking-side-wrapper clearfix">                 
<div class="booking-side">                  <!-- BEGIN .widget -->          
<div class="widget">  
<div class="widget-reservation-box">    
<h4 class="title-style2">Reservation</h4>    
<ul><li><span>Accomodation: </span> The Apartment</li>      
<li><span>Requested Dates: </span>       
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="one-half-form">
    <label for="open_date_from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="datefrom" name="book_date_from" value="Check In" class="datepicker">
</div>
<div class="one-half-form last-col">
    <label for="open_date_to">To</label>
    <input type="text" id="dateto" name="book_date_to" value="Check Out"   class="datepicker">
</div></div></li>   
<li><span>Number Of Guests: </span><select id="guests2"></select></li>      
<li><span>Total Days: <select id="days"></select></li>      
<li><span>Todays Date: </span>  <p id="today"></p></li> </ul>
<!-- END .widget-reservation-box -->  </div>            <!-- END .widget -->        </div>        <!-- END .content-wrapper -->  </div>
    </div>
<!-- booking form -->               
<div class="booking-main-wrapper">                  
<div class="booking-main">    
    <h4 class="title-style2">Your Details</h4>
<div class="input-left">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">    
<label for="email_address">Email Address</label>
 <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address">
<label for="phone_number">Telephone Number</label>
 <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number">
<label for="address_line1">Address Line 1</label>
 <input type="text" name="address_line1" id="address_line1">
    </div>
<div class="input-right">
<label for="address_line2">Address Line 2</label>
 <input type="text" name="address_line2" id="address_line2">
<label for="city">City</label>
 <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
<label for="state_county">State / County</label>
 <input type="text" name="state_county" id="state_county">
<label for="zip_postcode">Zip / Postcode</label>
 <input type="text" name="zip_postcode" id="zip_postcode">
<label for="country">Country</label>
 <input type="text" name="country" id="country">
    </div>
<label for="special_requirements">Special Requirments</label>   
 <textarea name="special_requirements" id="special_requirements" rows="10"></textarea>
<p class="terms"><input type="checkbox" name="terms"> I confirm I have read and agree to the <a href="#" style="color:#CC0000;font-weight:800;">terms and conditions</a> and wish to place a booking</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<input class="button1" type="submit" value="Request Booking Now" />    </form>          <hr class="space4"/>        </div>              </div>
</section>      
<!-- BEGIN #footer -->  <div id="footer">       <!-- BEGIN .content-wrapper -->     <div class="content-wrapper clearfix">                                      <!-- BEGIN #footer-bottom -->       <div id="footer-bottom" class="clearfix">
<nav class="secondary-navigation">      
<ul class="fr">
<li><a href="chalet.html">Chalet</a><span>/</span></li>
<li><a href="apartment.html">Apartment</a><span>/</span></li>
<li><a href="chalet_booking.html">Book Now</a><span>/</span></li>
<li><a href="location.html#directions">Directions &amp; Map</a><span>/</span></li>      
</ul>  </nav>    <!-- END .clearfix -->
</div> </div>       
<footer id="copyright">             
<div class="dyst">      
<p class="fl">&copy; Web adaptation, styling and graphics by</p><a href="http://www.dystopiart.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/DystopiART_Small.png" alt="DystopiART"></a>  
</div>  
<div class="social"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Beffay" class="link facebook" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook-square"></span></a>     
</div>  
<div class="rounded-corners scroll">    
<span class="to-top"><a href="#logo"><i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-2x">
</i></a></span>  </div>             
</footer>
</div></div></div></div></div>
<!-- Smooth Scroll -->
<script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<!-- END body -->
</body>
</html>
```

the scripts.js

```
    $(window).load(function(){"use strict"; // Text Slider$('.text-slider').flexslider({    animation: "fade",  controlNav: false,  directionNav: true, slideshow: true,    start: function(slider){        $('body').removeClass('loading');   }});
});
$(function() {
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
var select = document.getElementById("guests");
var option = document.createElement("OPTION");select.options.add(option);option.text = i;option.value = i;
}
});
$(function() {
for(var i=1; i<=28; i++){
var select = document.getElementById("days");
var option = document.createElement("OPTION");select.options.add(option);option.text = i;option.value = i;
}
});
$(function () {
$('#datefrom').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });$('#dateto').datepicker({ minDate: 1 });
});
$(function() {
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
});
$(function() {"use strict";// Datepicker$(".datepicker").datepicker();// Make Datepicker Fields Read Only$("#open_date_from").attr('readonly', true);$("#open_date_to").attr('readonly', true);// Booking page open datepicker$("#open_datepicker").datepicker({    numberOfMonths: 2,  minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: function(date) {     var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#open_date_from").val());      var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#open_date_to").val());        return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];   },  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {        var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#open_date_from").val());      var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#open_date_to").val());        if (!date1 || date2) {          $("#open_date_from").val(dateText);         $("#open_date_to").val("");     } else {            if(Date.parse(dateText) < Date.parse(date1)){               $("#open_date_from").val(dateText);             $("#open_date_to").val("");         }           else {              $("#open_date_to").val(dateText);           }       }   }});
});
```

mootools-cal-public.js- (for ajax calendar -amended calendar date clickable)

Comment: It would really help to post the code you're having problems with here

Comment: Error at  dateStart.set('value',dateFormat); is seen in console at line 56 of mootoolspublic.js ,

Comment: its my first time posting so please let me know anything else i need to add or information needed, any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your JS console. There are javascript errors on the not working page:

> TypeError: select is null
>
> select.options.add(option);

and

> TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
>
> $('.text-slider').flexslider({

Comment: I have added the js file to question for more information, the select options has been adapted from another thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742247/html-form-dropdown-menu-specify-number-range

Answer (score 0):

From both the above links what i can understand is that form on this page 
http://www.dystopiart.co.uk/Beffay_frame/chalet_booking.html supports datetimepicker, but form on this page http://www.dystopiart.co.uk/Beffay_frame/apartment_booking.html is not supportin the datatimepicker and reason being, i just tried checking your scripts file and can't find code to bind datetimepicker on date fields on the second field.
just try adding the below code to your scripts file

```
$('#datefrom2').datepicker();
$('#dateto2').datepicker();
```

Comment: amended as advised, unfortunately no change

Comment: Both the pages seems to support datepicker now

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your js/scripts.js a little
Replace this code:

```
    $(".datepicker",".datepicker2").datepicker();
```

With this code:

```
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

And at this page http://www.dystopiart.co.uk/Beffay_frame/apartment_booking.html
give date fields the same class like "datepicker"

Comment: made changes, so now just refers to same datepicker- i had added it in to try and resolve issue unsuccessfully.have also tried duplicate of the same page1, still wont run the javascript or jquery on second page